# Where is a chekbox to use the same device in Android Studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android-studio, adb

I noticed that can't select a device if several after first compilation of a project. A checkbox asking to use the same device for next launches is absent. How to revert it back?

[image]

Comment: I found a way to launch an application on another device with Instant Run. First click over red square (Stop app (Ctrl + F2), then this dialog appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable instant run in your android studio 3.0.1

**On MacOSX**

Go to `Preferences -> Build, Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run`

Uncheck the checkbox next to Enable Instant Run, Next time you'll see

**Use same device for future launches checkbox**

---